# Ranking of elements across different list

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have 3 lists as below :

```
List 1  List 2  List 3
A       A       D
D       D       M
GE      M       A
G       G       S
M       S       G
S       GE     GE
```

Now, i need to get the ranking of the elements in the list by averaging the elements rank across the list as explained below :

```
Elements    Rank-List1  Rank-List2  Rank-List3  Average     Ranking
A               1           1           3        1.67          1
D               2           2           1        1.67          2
GE              3           6           6        5             5
G               4           4           5        4.33          4
M               5           3           2        3.33          3
S               6           5           4        5             6
```

In case of match in Average, Pick the first element as higher rank.

So the final Output list will be :

```
Output list
A
D
M
G
GE
S
```

The average is calculated by  `Average = Sum of Rank (over all lists) / 3`:

```
( 1+1+3) / 3 = 1.67 # for A
```

Can this be achieved programitically in Python ?

Comment: No, kindly i am looking for the implementation code to understand.

Comment: Can you show the calculation of the average?

Comment: There are too many ways to approach this problem. The answers would just turn into a straw-poll for which one people liked. The best thing is to do some research on the topic yourself, find two or three, _analyze_ them, determine if they work for you or not, and _try them out_. Come to us when you have a specific question about something you have attempted to do.

Comment: @amanb, Calculation of average is simple = Sum of Rank / 3 ( 1+1+3 / 3 = 1.67 for A)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `key` argument of the `sorted` function:

```
list1 = ['A', 'D', 'GE', 'G', 'M', 'S']
list2 = ['A', 'D', 'M', 'G', 'S', 'GE']
list3 = ['D', 'M', 'A', 'S', 'G', 'GE']

sorted(list1, key=lambda elem: sum([list1.index(elem), list2.index(elem), list3.index(elem)]) / 3)
```

Or, for a list of lists:

```
lists = [['A', 'D', 'GE', 'G', 'M', 'S'],
         ['A', 'D', 'M', 'G', 'S', 'GE'],
         ['D', 'M', 'A', 'S', 'G', 'GE']]

sorted(lists[0], key=lambda elem: sum(sublist.index(elem) for sublist in lists) / len(lists))
```

Output for both cases above:

```
['A', 'D', 'M', 'G', 'GE', 'S']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Tomothy, exactly the same i was looking for. I learnt it.

Comment: this is awfully inefficient. Each call to `index()` iterates the whole list oncel fully.

Comment: Yes - your solution is O(n^2) - I added a O(n) one as answer. Comment on it if you need me to explain something in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import pandas as pd
>>>
>>> elements = ["A", "D", "GE", "G", "M", "S"]
>>> rank_list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> rank_list2 = [1, 2, 6, 4, 3, 5]
>>> rank_list3 = [3, 1, 6, 5, 2, 4]
>>>
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
...     "Elements": elements,
...     "Rank-List1": rank_list1,
...     "Rank-List2": rank_list2,
...     "Rank-List3": rank_list3,
... })
>>>
>>> df
  Elements  Rank-List1  Rank-List2  Rank-List3
0        A           1           1           3
1        D           2           2           1
2       GE           3           6           6
3        G           4           4           5
4        M           5           3           2
5        S           6           5           4
>>>
>>> df["Average"] = df.apply(lambda s: s[1:].mean(), axis=1)
>>> df
  Elements  Rank-List1  Rank-List2  Rank-List3   Average
0        A           1           1           3  1.666667
1        D           2           2           1  1.666667
2       GE           3           6           6  5.000000
3        G           4           4           5  4.333333
4        M           5           3           2  3.333333
5        S           6           5           4  5.000000
>>>
>>> df["Average"] = df.apply(lambda s: s[1:].mean().round(2), axis=1)
>>> df
  Elements  Rank-List1  Rank-List2  Rank-List3  Average
0        A           1           1           3     1.67
1        D           2           2           1     1.67
2       GE           3           6           6     5.00
3        G           4           4           5     4.33
4        M           5           3           2     3.33
5        S           6           5           4     5.00
>>>
>>> out = df.sort_values(by="Average")
>>> out
  Elements  Rank-List1  Rank-List2  Rank-List3  Average
0        A           1           1           3     1.67
1        D           2           2           1     1.67
4        M           5           3           2     3.33
3        G           4           4           5     4.33
2       GE           3           6           6     5.00
5        S           6           5           4     5.00
>>>
>>> out.Elements
0     A
1     D
4     M
3     G
2    GE
5     S
Name: Elements, dtype: object
>>>
>>> out.Elements.tolist()
['A', 'D', 'M', 'G', 'GE', 'S']
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks @hygull, i got it answered by Tomothy32

Answer (score 1):

Optimized version of [Tomothys solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54059943/7505395):

> sorted(list1, key=lambda elem: sum([list1.index(elem), list2.index(elem), list3.index(elem)]) / 3)

calls `.index()` 3 times for each element of `list1` - each call iterates the respective list (for each element in list1) until it finds the occurend - in total you get something like `sum([1,2,3,4,5,6])` three times which is `63` (instead of `18` - see below).

The complexity of my solution is ruled by `O(n)` where `n = sum(len(item) for item in data) => 18` - the complexity of the sorting is negliable as it operates only on the `set()` of items over all lists which is much smaller. [Timsort complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort#Analysis) needs (worst case) `O(m*log(m))` where `m = set(i for sub in data for i in sub) => 6`

---

```
from collections import defaultdict

data = [['A', 'D', 'GE', 'G', 'M', 'S'], ['A', 'D', 'M', 'G', 'S', 'GE'],
        ['D', 'M', 'A', 'S', 'G', 'GE']]

d = defaultdict(list) # or int and use /3.0 implicitly

# this loop touches each element once:  O(n) n = sum(length of all lists)
for l in data:
    for idx,value in enumerate(l):
        d[value].append(idx)

# timsort: O(m) to O(m*log(m)) for the much shorter set() over emelents of all lists)  
# sort by score:
result = sorted(d.items(), key= lambda x:sum(x[1])/float(len(x[1]))) 
print( *(r  for r in result), sep="\n") # use 'r[0] for r ..' to just print the names
```

Output:

```
('A', [0, 0, 2])
('D', [1, 1, 0])
('M', [4, 2, 1])
('G', [3, 3, 4])
('GE', [2, 5, 5])
('S', [5, 4, 3])
```

---

If you guarantee that each sublist contains the same elements - just in a different order you can simplify further:

```
d = defaultdict(int) 

# this loop touches each element once:  O(n)
for l in data:
    for idx,value in enumerate(l):
        d[value]+=idx

# there is no sense in dividing the sum by 3 if _all_ sums have to be devided by it

# sort by score:
result = sorted(d.items()) 
print( *(r  for r in result), sep="\n")
```

Output:

```
('A', 2)
('D', 2)
('G', 10)
('GE', 12)
('M', 7)
('S', 12)
```

---

`defaultdict` is faster then using normal dicts - but if you do not like to import you can change it against the slower

```
d = {}
d.setdefault(key, []).append(value)  # defaultdict(list)
d.setdefault(key, 0) += value      # defaultdict(int)
```

`setdefault(key,default)` is slower because it always constructs `default` which takes time - defaultdict(...) is optimized to not need this and so it is (slightly) faster.